# script to map drive in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a ps1 script that will take a users AD password as a variable then pass that to the New-Psdrive commandlet. The drive they are mapping is shared so that if they enter the correct credentials it will map, with no need to check AD for the correct username/password.

I want to be able to give them 3 chances of entering the correct credentials before the script will exit.

So far I have

```
$Credential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "NetBiosUserName")

New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\servername -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Ignore
```

When called i get a username/password box and if credentials are correct the drive is mapped, but I want the box to pop back up if the credentials are incorrect, and potentially happen again if the wrong ones are entered again

I got as far as

> try {$Credential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "NetBiosUserName")
> New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \servername -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Ignore}
> catch {write-host "incorrect, try again"}

Then repeating this, but when the credentials are correct, it still pops up the credential window

thanks for any help!

Comment: you can look hier https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Thanks, i have the mapping working ok, I just want to have a loop...

I was trying a try{} catch{} finally{} for the loop but this kept popping up the credential box even if they had been entered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I added a test because PSDrive will be created if the user cancel the credential dialog :

```
while ($true)
{
    try
    {
        $Credential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "NetBiosUserName")

        # Prevent cancel that maps PSDrive anyway
        if ($Credential)
        {
            New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\servername\share -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        else
        {
            throw [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new(0x80004005)   # Invalid login and/or password
        }
        "OK"

        # PSSDrive created, exiting the infinite loop
        break
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Wrong Username and/or password, please retry..."
    }
}
"Continue"
```

Comment: As a matter of interest, could I add another drive to be mapped just below this line?

New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\servername\share -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop

Comment: you should be able to add as many as youd like

Comment: as @Abraham Zinala said, yes :) You should mark this question as answered so that it not be shown in "questions not anwsered"

Comment: @CFou I have added a new drive mapping with the same syntax, but different drive letter and folder and it does not map...I get an error as if I have entered incorrect details, but the first drive maps fine....the script is now stuck in a loop saying "wrong username and/or......."

I have tried running just the $credential line, and the 2 drive mapping lines on their own, and this works ok....

Comment: I have done some further testing on the above script, and it works fine with more drives added as @CFou said, thanks for your help!